# Why timestamp is not saved to React state object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

I am trying to save the date as a timestamp in Firebase, but for some reason, the timestamp does not save to state from form onChange handler...

```
const [event, setEvent] = useState({});

function handleDate(e) {
  e.persist();
  let d = e.target.value;
  console.log('date1', d); //date1 2020-10-13
  let dd = new Date(d);
  console.log('date2', dd); // Tue Oct 13 2020 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
  let ddd = dd.getTime() / 1000;
  console.log('timestamp ', ddd); // timestamp  1602547200
  setEvent({...event, date_ts: ddd});
  console.log('event timestamp', event.date_ts); //null
  setEvent({...event, date: e.target.value});
  console.log('event date', event.date); // empty string
}
```

Finally the event.date property is saved correct, but event.date_ts is null. Why??
And secondly... Why the "event date" console log from the handler is an empty string but the date gets saved?
Thanks

**EDIT:**

It is right now very basic Firebase save:

```
    const saveNewEvent = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log("save event", event) //HERE the time_ts is "null"
        firebase.firestore().collection(event.category).add({
            event
        })
        setEvent({ ...defalut_event })
    }
```

...so it looks like it is some React weirdness, nothing to do with Firebase... (or maybe my incompetence, rather ;)

Comment: `setEvent` is async function, put your log into `useEffect` to track when `event` changed

Comment: but why the difference between date and date_ts??? date_ts is still null after push to Firebse...

Comment: @oskar333: `event` isn't assigned a new value until the next render.

Answer (score 0):

You can read [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) for more info.

Basically when you execute this:

```
setEvent({ ...event, date_ts: ddd })
```

Reactjs will not update the `event` object immediately. For performance reason, it will batch multiple `setEvent` and call `render` once.

So when you call this:

```
console.log("event timestamp", event.date_ts) //null
```

The `event` is not the latest value which you set in previous line yet.

If you want to get latest value, you need to use lifecycle hook, as described [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Comment: but why the difference between date and date_ts??? date_ts is still null after push to Firebse...

Comment: @oskar333 you didn't show the code on how you post the data to firebase

Comment: Sam, plese see the Edit above.

Comment: @oskar333 it depends when you call this `saveNewEvent`, is it after `handleDate`? Your comment there mentioned `time_ts` is null but your `handDate` there doesn't handle `time_ts`, I suggest you put your completed code in jsfiddle so we can help you further.

Comment: Of course I am trying to save the date after "handling" it :) `handleDate` DOES handle time_ts, I have ONE form date input and as shown `time_ts` time stamp is generated from default browser input `e.target.value`. Threre is nothing else in the code... that is why it is so confusing to me... the app is to big to put in jsfidddle....